# Statement to extract only a unique record matching a condition

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with multiple customer records. Each customer has multiple records (different product ownership quantities). Some of these customers are 'dummy' customers. I need a SQL query to show me the records where ONLY the dummy customers have quantities in any of the products, and not any records where dummy and real customers have ownership records. In other words, I need to see the records where the dummy customers are the only ones having an ownership of a product where all of the real customers have no ownership.

Tried the `is null` and `is not null` statements but this merely shows the records matching that one condition. I also tried `WHERE EXISTS` but no luck.

```
SELECT ACCT_ID, PRDCT_id, QUANTITY
FROM dbo.POSITION
WHERE ACCT_ID = 'FUTUR' AND QUANTITY > '0.1'

WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ACCT_ID, PRDCT_id, QUANTITY FROM dbo.POSITION WHERE QUANTITY < '1' AND ACCT_ID <> 'FUTUR')
AND ACCT_ID = 'FUTUR'
```

I expect the output to show me the records of the 'FUTUR' dummy customer where it holds any quantity of a product where all of the Real customers have no holdings.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for ideas on how to make this question answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - you get one of these. If you want help, you encourage others to do so by providing a script that demonstrates your issue - a MVCE which is one of the links suggested. Here is one example of generating the information you desired

```
set nocount on;
declare @position table (
    acct_id varchar(15) not null, prod_id smallint not null, quantity int not null, 
    primary key (acct_id, prod_id)
    );

-- populate sample data
insert @position(acct_id, prod_id, quantity) 
values ('futur', 1, 10), ('zork', 1, 12), ('futur', 2, 11), ('zork', 3, 2), ('diablo', 3, 3), ('diablo', 4, 10), ('wow', 1, 5);

-- look at everything
select * from @position
order by prod_id, acct_id;

-- dummy positions
select * from @position as fake 
where acct_id = 'futur'
--and not exists (select * from @position as notfake where notfake.acct_id <> 'futur' and notfake.prod_id = fake.prod_id)
order by prod_id;

-- dummy positions that no real customer also has
select * from @position as fake 
where acct_id = 'futur'
and not exists (select * from @position as notfake where fake.acct_id <> notfake.acct_id and notfake.prod_id = fake.prod_id)
order by prod_id;
```

Notice the sample data. There is a dummy position in 2 products, only 1 of those is not associated with any other "real" customer.

Notice the logic in the where clause - it uses a correlated subquery to find rows where the product id is the same but the account id is different. Since the outer query selects rows for the dummy customer only, the subquery will find matching rows for any other (i.e., not dummy) customers. You want to see the non-matches, so it uses "not exists" with the subquery.

Also notice that I did not check the quantity at all. It doesn't really make sense to have a position of zero for a product and I would expect such rows to not exist. You can add that check if you need to. If you do, I suggest you think long and hard about why rows of zero quantity should be stored at all. Over time, will these just "clog" the table with useless information.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? You want all the products where all of its `ACCT_ID`s are `FUTUR`:

```
SELECT PRDCT_id
FROM dbo.POSITION
WHERE QUANTITY > 0.1 -- I'm not sure whether/how quantity factors into the problem
GROUP BY PRDCT_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN ACCT_ID = 'FUTUR' THEN 1 END);
```

You shouldn't need to quote the value 0.1 in the comparison either. If this is a numeric column then use a numeric literal too.